# How can i truncate the sysdate[ Getdata()] function in sql Server 2008r2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008-r2

Oracle:

```
select j.Jobname,rg.Region,wc.Status from Job j,Region rg,Weekend_Check_Detail wc
where j.Row_id=wc.Job_ID and Region_ID=rg.Row_id
and trunc(wc.StartTime)=trunc(sysdate)
order by rg.Region
```

`trunc(wc.StartTime)=trunc(sysdate)`
How do i write equivalent for the above in sqlserver 2008?

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what you are trying to achieve. Not every SQL specialist is familiar with the Oracle dbms.

Comment: A sample of data input and required output would help

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Convert` function

ex:

```
select   CONVERT(date, getdate())
```

or in your case

```
select j.Jobname, rg.Region, wc.Status
from Job j,
     Region rg,
     Weekend_Check_Detail wc
where j.Row_id = wc.Job_ID
  and Region_ID = rg.Row_id
  and CONVERT(date, wc.StartTime) = CONVERT(date, getdate())
order by rg.Region
```

Comment: Please be aware that CONVERT is not ANSI compliant, while CAST is.
So if ANSI compliancy is important, use `and CAST(wc.StartTime AS date) = CAST(GETDATE() AS date)`.

Comment: It's a floating point value so I hardly doubt that it is an issue. but thank you for reminding me of it.

Comment: It's all about portability to other platforms. CONVERT will not work on all dbms.

Comment: Then we are lucky that it is in the SQL Server group this question is found.

Comment: @PeterElzinga: `GETDATE()` is also **not** ANSI compliant so it doesn't matter if `convert()` or `cast()`  is used. An ANSI SQL compliant condition would be `and cast(startTime as DATE) = current_date`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: You're completely right, thanks for the addition!